# How to Access Your Ubuntu Bash Files in Windows

Tags: ubuntu

```
h111@DESKTOP-3D1U1A2:~$ /mnt
-bash: /mnt: Is a directory
h111@DESKTOP-3D1U1A2:~$ /mnt/c
-bash: /mnt/c: Is a directory
h111@DESKTOP-3D1U1A2:~$ cd/mnt/c
-bash: cd/mnt/c: No such file or directory
ho111@DESKTOP-3D1U1A2:~$ cd/mnt/c
-bash: cd/mnt/c: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space between the `cd` command and the `/mnt/c` path:

```
$ cd /mnt/c
```